# Recommended method or software to make spinner tokens

Tags: print-design, text-wrap

[image: Prototype design]

Shown is a prototype from a hybrid board game/RPG featuring poker chip-like tokens that are spun to receive numeric results. Different tokens may have different ranges of values on them, and I may have to change these in response to playtests. So, what I need in design capabilities:

- Subdivide a circle into a specific number of segments, in alternating colors for legibility. I also need additional segment colors to represent special outcomes (like getting a car or jackpot in Wheel of Fortune)
- Distribute text across the circle sections representing the possible outcomes. These also need to be in alternating colors for legibility, and be placed outside the inner circle of the token, which contains explanatory text about what the token does.

I made this prototype in Inkscape, and I found it somewhat problematic. Making the circular sections was easy enough, but it was tedious enough that I wouldn't like to have to do it from scratch every time I need a circle with a different number of sections. Getting the text was the hardest part. It was easy to wrap it onto a circle, but then I had to fiddle with the spacing manually to get it to fit neatly into the sections. I also had to manually change the color of each alternating letter. Ultimately, it's not a nightmare, but I'm looking for a more streamlined process.

Comment: Inkscape or Illustrator would be tools I'd suggest. Text on a circle isn't often easily achieved in other apps. The vector nature of Inscape/Illustrator makes them ideal. It may be that you weren't well versed in Inkscape methods. The reality is, set this up correctly once and you have a template for all future setups.

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape is ideal for this, but from the description of what you did, it seems a little over complicated.

You could instead create one segment and one number, group them, and create the rest by duplicating and rotating.

Here's an example. This took me about 3 minutes.

[image]

Comment: Note that it would also be possible to use Text on a Path if you really want the numbers to flow better around the circle. The group and duplicate trick will still work, and you will still only need one number to start with.